# C++ Possible to make a destructor NOT call the destructor of class members and the destructor of the base class?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make a destructor of a class NOT call the destructor of one of the class members and/or NOT call the destructor of its base class?

In case this is not possible, is creating certain class members with placement-new and destructing (/not-destructing) them manually a possible workaround? Thanks!

EDIT:
The reason I need this: Class C owns object M. M has a non-trivial destructor. C is friend of M and manages M in a way that there is no need to call M's destructor. It is OK to call it but it means performance overhead. (it's a problem in this case.)
I was thinking to make an a derived class from M that has a destructor that does nothing, but then that would still call the destructor of the base.

Comment: This is a terrible thing to do and will make maintenance a nightmare. But yes, C++ allows you to shoot yourself like this using placement new.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve by "not calling destructors"? Your question is a prime example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Why? What is your real goal? This sounds very dodgy. Professional responsibility dictates that I do not help with this unless there's a very good reason!

Comment: Are you *trying* to leak memory? Maybe trying to get a (minuscule) speed boost by not calling those pesky destructors? I don't get what you're aiming to achieve with this.

Comment: So you'd rather it wasn't a destructor at all? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: thanking anybody who might help you with this is a very sarcastic thing to do.  Any real programmer will find an alternate design solution.  Rethink your question so that "Thanks" isn't insulting.

Comment: Made an edit to explain why I was considering this. I don't understand the down-vote since its a question like "does c++ has a feature like this". The class is a container-class that would be used very frequently, I wouldn't be trying to find weird workarounds otherways.

Comment: Empty destructors are very good targets for inlining. You will likely not see any destructor call in the assembly if the destructor doesn't do anything.

Comment: _"M has a non-trivial destructor. C [..] manages M in a way that there is no need to call M's destructor."_ That just makes zero sense. It there's a performance overhead in the destructor, that means it _does a thing_. If you think you don't want to do that thing, either you're wrong, or that thing shouldn't be in a destructor in the first place. I realise you're not asking for a critique of your design but a specific answer to a question; still, as I said above, it would be irresponsible for us to answer your question without more context. We have a duty of care, after all!

Comment: @nwp actually it is not allowed: if an object is created with `new` (placement or not), and the storage is later freed or re-used without the destructor being invoked, and the destructor has side-effects, then it is undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M Really? I was under the impression clobbering (non-POD) objects was allowed.

Comment: @nwp see [basic.life]/4 (C++14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At construction time, C++ ensures that the subclasses contructors are first called, then the members are contructed, and finally the appropriate constructor is applied. At destruction time the symetric is done.

That means that you cannot prevent the application of a base class destructor, nor of any member constructor, **as soon as the object is destructed**. If you want to only destruct some, you must find a way to not destruct the object (just use a raw pointer...) and manually call destructors on what you want. But you certainly do not want to do that!

C++ is very confident on the programmer skills, so it is easy to write a program invoking undefined behaviour. If you find yourself trying to subvert the C++ compiler to not call the destructor of a base class or of a member, you have a major problem. The *member* you do not want to destroy should not be a member but more probably a pointer (raw or shared) or a reference to an external object that will have its own lifetime management. And the *base class* should probably also be a pointer or reference to an external object, and here again the lifetime can (and should) be managed outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If the destructor has observable side-effects, then it would be undefined behaviour to end the lifetime of the object without invoking the destructor. This is covered in C++14 [basic.life]/4:

> A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor. For an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a delete-expression is not used to release the storage, the destructor shall not be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

So, there is no way to get around it. Perhaps you could redesign your code so that the destructor doesn't execute any unnecessary statements, or something.